# How to pass key to react route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am separating routes based on roles. Each PrivateRoute is a route.

**Route.tsx**

```
export default function MCRoutes({ isUserAuthenticated, role }) {
  const token = useFetchToken();
  // const { data } = useFetchDataFromState("activeModule");

  let privateRoutes = mcRoutesConfig[role].routes.map(
    ({ id, component, path, exact }) => (
      <PrivateRoute
        // key={id}
        exact={exact}
        isUserAuthenticated
        path={path}
        component={component}
      />
    )
  );

  return (
    <Switch>
      {privateRoutes}
      <Route component={NoPageFound} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

**PrivateRoute**

```
export default function PrivateRoute({
  component: Component,
  isUserAuthenticated,
  ...props
}) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      render={innerProps => {
        return isUserAuthenticated ? (
          <PrivateLayout>
            <Component {...innerProps} />
          </PrivateLayout>
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

But when I do this, React asks me to provide key for each item in map function. And if I pass key as prop then it remounts components when route changes. How to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `path` prop as `key` value?

Comment: Yup, but it did not work.

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5972. It says that if the key is not the same as the key that was before, React remounts the component.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use the same key for all routes. No warning and seems like it works just fine.

```
const Routes = ({ routes }) => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            {routes.map(props => {
                return <RouteWithLayout key={1} {...props} />
            })}
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

This is most probably working due to how `Switch` works. It'll check paths and renders the only one exactly that matches.

Answer (score -1):

The map function in JS provides a second argument to the function you give it, which is the index of the current iteration. The React community suggests that you can use that if you cannot use other properties.

So you could do like this:

```
...

let privateRoutes = mcRoutesConfig[role].routes.map(
  ({ id, component, path, exact }, index) => (
    <PrivateRoute
      key={index}
      exact={exact}
      isUserAuthenticated
      path={path}
      component={component}
    />
  )
);

return ...
```

That should work.

Comment: Providing key makes component remount.

Comment: @Piyush Have you got any solution for this? Actually I am also stuck in the same problem.